# Finding the size of an obtuse angle

Tags: geometry, triangles, angle

[image: triangle ABC]

In the diagram, $|BX|$ is the bisector of angle $ABC$ and $|CX|$ is the bisector of angle $ACB$, if angle $A=68$. Find the size of the obtuse angle $BXC$.

Comment: Do you know what the sum of all angles in a triangle is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint. $\frac{1}{2}\angle B+ \frac{1}{2}\angle C=\frac{1}{2}(180-68)$.

Comment: Thanks so much... that helps... angle BXC = 124 using the hint.

Comment: @Samuel Olumoyeke Well done!